# Why isn't the line in my graph showing up?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want a graph that shows how much the objects acceleration is going up from the force.
The line plot at the end is not showing anything but labels.

```
import numpy as np;
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time as tme;

Acceleration, MASS = (float(0), float(2.5))
Force = 0


isMotion = False

def addForce(newtons):
  global Acceleration
  global MASS

  accelAmount = []

  repAmount = 0
  while repAmount < newtons:
    repAmount += 1

    accelAmount.append(repAmount)
    print(accelAmount)
    tme.sleep(.2)
  
  for i in accelAmount:
    Acceleration += float(1.5)
    ma = MASS * Acceleration
    global Force
    Force = ma
    print(f'Force = {round(Force)} Newtons | ({i})')
    global A
    A = Acceleration
    global F
    F = Force

addForce(10)
plt.plot(F, A)
plt.title('Force & Acceleration')
plt.xlabel('Force')
plt.ylabel('Acceleration')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `F` and `A` are floats, not iterables (lists or arrays). Matplotlib plots a graph with one point, which does not show, because the default style does not highlights points, it only prints graphs.

You need to fix the code in `addForce()` to produce arrays for both variables.

Comment: Ohh! Thank you! It is working now.

Comment: @TheWall Glad to help. Please mark my answer as correct.